# Responsive navbar with onclick search bar

Tags: html, css, search, navbar, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive navbar which sits in-line with a few other icons on my website.

I have it working on desktop mode, but I am struggling with the mobile view.

The main issue I'm having is that I cannot collapse the search bar so when you click the magnifying glass the search bar will pop up below the navbar. 
Lining up all 5 icons so that it looks neat.

Below I have attached 3 images:

The first one is where I am currently at with my site
The second Site is What I want to achieve
The Third is how it looks in desktop mode with the search bar working.

[image: <code>first image</code>]
[image: Second Image]
[image]

I have also attached a js Fiddle with all the content that I currently have.

https://jsfiddle.net/kLo8x29u/

```
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">      

  <a class='home'href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Building Materials</a>
  <a href="#">Timber and Hardwood</a>
  <a href="#">Landscaping</a>
  <a href="#">Kitchens and Bathrooms</a>
  <a href="#">Tools</a>
  <a href="#">Flooring</a>
  <a href="#">Tool Hire</a>
  <a class='timber' href="#a">Timber Enginering</a>

       <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
   <i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size:56px"><p>Home</p></i>
  </a>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip: if you want the JSFiddle to display properly, you need to upload the images to somewhere (imgur maybe?), and link them there, otherwise we just see question marks, and it's harder to tell what is going on.

Comment: Hi @user770 thanks for the response! Unfortunatley they are SVG icon's and cannot be uploaded, the main issue i'm having is creating a toggle responsive search bar, if it makes it easier I could simply take the broken links out?

Comment: Maybe take a screenshot of the result locally (so images are visible), crop the screenshot to obtain similarly sized images, and upload/link those.

Comment: @user770 https://jsfiddle.net/kLo8x29u/1/ here is a new fiddle with no images in it just to avoid the confusion! I hope this helps!

Comment: It does have the images. Did you click "save"?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kLo8x29u/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align your icons, you have to put the icons and the menu in the same div with an id; Then you give it a position relative and display inline-block. After this, all the icons have to have float left, so that they will be positioned in line. The way you have your code, youre not informing it that you want to have the icons side by side :) if you still need some help, I can help you

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the tip, have you any idea on how to make the search bar appear below the navbar when clicked?

Comment: with js you can add a class to it that is going to be actived when clicked. For example: you set display none for the search box and when it is clicked ja is going to change the class to actev and display block.

Comment: That's perfect exactly what I need thanks, I'm pretty new to JS so it will take a few tries but I reckon i'll crack it, eventually! thanks!

Comment: Am i able to set it so that this only happens during mobile view? using a media query?